# Asterisk 13, AMI, Queue, NewChannel Local

Tags: asterisk

I have Asterisk certified-13.13-cert4, Queue and 20+ operators.
In most case AMI events like Case 1 and Case 2, but sometimes like Case 3.

`Case 1:
1 09:11:44,092 Newchannel SIP/AST-750-0013a24d
2 09:11:44,097 Newstate SIP/AST-750-0013a24d Ring
3 09:11:44,101 Newstate SIP/AST-750-0013a24d Up
4 09:11:58,301 Newchannel SIP/70107-0013a256
5 09:11:58,419 Newstate SIP/70107-0013a256 Ringing
6 09:12:01,727 Newstate SIP/70107-0013a256 Up
7 09:12:50,955 HangupRequest SIP/70107-0013a256
8 09:12:50,957 Hangup SIP/70107-0013a256
9 09:12:50,960 Hangup SIP/AST-750-0013a24d`

Case 2:
 1 09:37:54,864 Newchannel SIP/AST-750-0013a989
 2 09:37:54,874 Newstate SIP/AST-750-0013a989 Ring
 3 09:37:54,882 Newstate SIP/AST-750-0013a989 Up
 4 09:38:09,116 Newchannel SIP/70107-0013a993
 5 09:38:09,232 Newstate SIP/70107-0013a993 Ringing
 6 09:38:09,238 Hangup SIP/70107-0013a993
 7 09:38:09,241 Newchannel SIP/70202-0013a994
 8 09:38:09,338 Newstate SIP/70202-0013a994 Ringing
 9 09:38:14,069 Newstate SIP/70202-0013a994 Up
10 09:39:49,341 HangupRequest SIP/70202-0013a994
11 09:39:49,379 Hangup SIP/70202-0013a994
12 09:39:49,391 Hangup SIP/AST-750-0013a989

Case 3:
 1 09:40:39,208 Newchannel SIP/AST-750-0013aa1c
 2 09:40:39,213 Newstate SIP/AST-750-0013aa1c Ring
 3 09:40:39,216 Newstate SIP/AST-750-0013aa1c Up
 4 09:40:53,334 Newchannel SIP/70107-0013aa25
 5 09:40:53,470 Newstate SIP/70107-0013aa25 Ringing
 6 09:40:53,473 Newchannel Local/70107@from-operators-00002a78;1
 7 09:40:53,475 Newchannel Local/70107@from-operators-00002a78;2
 8 09:40:53,477 Newchannel SIP/70107-0013aa26
 9 09:40:53,478 Hangup SIP/70107-0013aa25
10 09:40:53,611 Newstate SIP/70107-0013aa26  Ringing
11 09:40:53,612 Newstate Local/70107@from-operators-00002a78;1  Ringing
12 09:41:03,339 HangupRequest Local/70107@from-operators-00002a78;2
13 09:41:03,340 Hangup SIP/70107-0013aa26
14 09:41:03,342 Hangup Local/70107@from-operators-00002a78;2
15 09:41:03,343 Hangup Local/70107@from-operators-00002a78;1
16 09:41:08,347 Newchannel SIP/70109-0013aa2c
17 09:41:08,461 Newstate SIP/70109-0013aa2c Ringing
18 09:41:09,668 SIP/70109-0013aa2c Up
19 09:41:53,054 HangupRequest SIP/AST-750-0013aa1c
20 09:41:53,056 Hangup SIP/70109-0013aa2c
21 09:41:53,064 Hangup SIP/AST-750-0013aa1c

Why in Case 2 events 4-6, but the same thing in Case 3 events 4-15?

Below parts of queues.conf, extensions.conf, sip.conf and AMI log for cases.
https://pastebin.com/yRq1fjbJ

Answer (score 0):

Queue can generate one or more calls.

Each call can be repeated or not.

That depend of your settings and number of agents availible at any single model.

You SHOULD NOT use events for queue monitoring, use queue_log.

Comment: It's not monitoring. I develop realtime CTI application for call center.

Comment: So you have rewrite your application or rewrite queues.